# Send an interrupt to the kernel form shell

Tags: linux, interrupts

I am writing a linux module, and I want to test it, so right now it should be triggered when an interrupt happens, so before testing it for real, I want to send the interrupt by hand and see what happens. I have tried writing `kill 8 0`. But nothing happened.

- Is `kill` filtering interrupts to the kernel?
- Is there a way to issue an interrupt from the shell?

Note, I'm working with interrupt 8 which should be a hardware interrupt.

Answer (score -1):

Why you think that signal must be forwarded to your module?
I think you must write new syscall to testing your module. you can calling your module function in your syscall for testing. and calling your syscall in C program.

C sample-->new syscall with args(that arg specify modules func)-->your module function.

Comment: Ugh, this is hard to read. I am not sure what you are getting at either. Can you expand this with real information, otherwise delegate it to a comment and delete this as an answer.\

Comment: Well, if I take over the IDT (which is the place that the OS checks what to do when an interrupt happens) then my function should be executed. I have another code which took over the pagefault interrupt, works like a charm on every pagefault. But when I switched it to the rtc - somehow nothing is happening.